How do I configure log4j2-elasticsearch-hc with ApiKey authorization?
I'm using Java 21, grade 8. I'm using properties configuration. Every configuration example I've found has not worked. The primary problem is the ApiKey authorization header requirement. I can't find anything showing that which works.

I am not familiar with log4j2-elasticsearch-hc but I reviewed the code I couldn't find any parts of it that would implement ApiKey authentication. I see the code that implements basic authentication, and I see that it is pluggable but I am afraid you would need to write your own CredentialsPlugin to achieve that, I don't think it can do it out of the box.
